# Select Layer By Attribute: SQL Expression using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, sql, select-by-attribute

I am currently using ArcMap 10.3's ModelBuilder. Having created a feature class of 300 zones, I would like to filter these to the 15 zones above 200 hectares in size, the model is shown below:

[image: End of the model]

I have tried to use the following SQL Code to achieve this, but it never has an effect when running the model.

[image: SQL code]

Comment: `"Shape_Length" < 2000000` is everything **less** than 200 hectares, not everything greater than 200

Comment: Ah apologies, that was left from a previous attempt to delete the selected data and leave what I wanted, the code does not work either way.

Comment: Can you confirm that `Shape_Length` is the correct field?  Hectares is an area value so I would expect a field called `Shape_Area` or similar.

Comment: You are of course correct, I assure you I have been using Shape_Area, I just mis-clicked when setting up that screenshot. Previously when clicking "Get unique values" I was not presented with any data, however this has since changed and I don't know why... I will update if I find out why....

Comment: I can't see your entire model - is there a Join in there at all?  in the past I have found that I can't select by the Shape length/area fields if the layer is joined to another table.

Comment: So I got it to work in the end, I'll add the answer below, thank you so much for taking the time to help though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Sequence of Tools]

This sequence of tools successfully selected the right areas. While setting up the "Select" tool, the "Get Unique Values" button for "Shape_Area" still did not get any values (as the Feature Class does not exist before the model is run), however this sequence of tools meant that entering the correct expression gave the correct result.

In a nutshell the problem was in the processing before selection, not the selection itself.